# Default shell in MobaXterm

Tags: wsl2, ubuntu-20.04, mobaxterm, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows Server 2022 which I recently had to reinstall. On this server, I am running WSL with an Ubuntu 20.04 installation.

Before my reinstall I used MobaXterm to connect to the Ubuntu shell on WSL since it supports multiple tabs which PowerShell doesn't. So I installed MobaXterm again, but now I have come across a problem.

In my old installation I was able to set the "default shell/session/terminal" to be Ubuntu 20.04 instead of the default terminal with "/home/mobaxterm". This means that every time I either clicked "Start local terminal" or the "+"-sign it opened my WSL-Ubuntu shell.

But now when installing it again, I cannot for my life find where I can change this setting anymore. I have been googling and searching here but nothing helps.

Does anyone know where I can set this?

Comment: You are probably looking for [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmHJj.png) option but Windows Terminal also supports multiple tabs.